# All my files are on my blog! I need sync solution

Tags: uploads

I uploaded all my files on my blog (self hosted). Now all my files (documents, photos, etc...) are somewhere in wp-content/upoads folder...

Is there a way of having all my files in their folders (documents in docs folder, photos in photos, etc) but still have them available trough wordpress...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Settings -> Media -> Uploading Files`